# Augmenting Rows With Value From T-SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2012 to import an Excel file into a database. One of the fields I need to populate into the database on import cannot be stored in the Excel file. The value that goes into the field can only be known at the time the record is being created in the database. The particular software I am using stores the last used value for this field in a separate database. When creating the records on import I need to increment this field and insert the new value in the new record. I have a T-SQL script that generates this value but I don't know enough about SSIS to know how to get that value for each row during Import.

Here's the script that I'm using to generate the value I need:

```
--Declare some variables
DECLARE @I_sCompanyID smallint,
@O_mNoteIndex numeric(19,5),
@O_iErrorState int

--Get the CompanyID
select @I_sCompanyID = CMPANYID
from DYNAMICS..SY01500
where INTERID = DB_Name()

--Get and increment the next note index
exec DYNAMICS.[dbo].[smGetNextNoteIndex] @I_sCompanyID, 1, @O_mNoteIndex output, @O_iErrorState output

--Print the Next Note Index
SELECT @O_mNoteIndex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option that comes to mind is to use a `Script Component` to add a column named O_mNoteIndex into your data flow. You will basically need to use your above TSQL code and either work with [OleDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.aspx), [SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) or [Odbc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.aspx) to query the Dynamics server and generate your id.

You will need to add the column into your output buffer and assign that the tsql value. I'm not finding any of my previous answers that explore how to do this but the [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188192.aspx) site ought to get you started

Comment: Thanks, I have a script component already doing other work. I can add this as part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run the above script and return the result into a SSIS variable. Then add that variable in a computed column transform. That is assuming you need to just run that script once before you load your dataset. If you need to run it per record, you need to go @billinkc's method.

Or if you want to avoid script you could load your source data into an OLEDB recordset and then use that in a For Each Loop and call that script for each iteration of the loop